# When i pass array in category id it works but when i pass php variable it will not works

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I want to fetch posts of custom post tpye when i pass cat id direct in query it works fine for me giving posts of all category id but when i pass these category id in a varible like $catid = array(154,153,155);
and then pass this $cat id it will not work

```
global $wpdb;
    global $posts;
    $catId = $args['categoryid'];
    $perPage = $args['post_per_page'];
    print_r($catId);
    $posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => $perPage,
        'post_type' => 'blog',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'blog_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => array($catId)

            )
        )
    )
);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($posts_array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode comma separated string in `$args['categoryid']` to get an array and then pass below to function

```
global $wpdb;
global $posts;
$catId = explode(',',$args['categoryid']);
$perPage = $args['post_per_page'];

$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => $perPage,
        'post_type' => 'blog',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'blog_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $catId,
                'operator' => 'IN'

            )
        )
    )
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($posts_array);
```

Comment: try to remove the array from 'terms' => array($catId).  Just pass 'terms' => $catId

Comment: can u print the array passed inside get_posts() and show it to me in comment

Comment: Array ( [categoryid] => 153,154,155 [post_per_page] => 10 )

Comment: Array
(
    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [post_type] => blog
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => blog_cat
                    [field] => term_id
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 153,154,155
                        )

                    [operator] => IN
                )

        )

)

Comment: please tick the answer